# Poisson/ jump process distribution for process $z(t)=2t+B(t)+\sum_{k=0}^{X(t)} J_k$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For the process:
$z(t)=2t+B(t)+\sum_{k=0}^{X(t)} J_k$, 
where $X(t)$ is a poisson process with paramater $\lambda$, and: $J_k$ are i.i.d . random variables (jumps). $B(t)$=brownian motion.

I want to compute the distribution of $z$. Can someone show me how to start?

I know that for a time interval $dt$, the  probability for a jump is $\lambda dt$, but I don't know what to do with it..
I found [here](http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/200471712338602.pdf) on page 26 that:  $E[f(X_t)]= \lambda t \int f(y)G(x,dy)+(1-\lambda t)f(x)$ but I don't why this is valid?

Comment: What is $B(t)$? If it is not important, remove it.

Comment: @SergioParreiras $B(t)$=browian motion